# Laravel - Redirects to https

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel framework. Except the home page, every other page redirects to https which doesn't work when using "php artisan serve". I checked routes.php and middleware I couldn't find any such thing in configuration that forces https.

Routes:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function() {


Route::controller('/form', 'Admin\FormController');
.....

............


Route::controller('/guide', 'Admin\GuideController');


Route::controller('/userlist', 'Admin\UserController');
Route::controller('/useradd', 'Admin\UserController');

Route::controller('/locationlist', 'Admin\LocationController');
Route::controller('/locationadd', 'Admin\LocationController');



Route::controller('/', 'Admin\AdminController');

});



Route::controller('/', 'Site\SiteController');
```

htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://....../$1 [R,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>

php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
```

Comment: edit your question and upload .htaccess file code

Comment: your problem is in the `.htaccess` file

Comment: @Jadoon Added htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

you can solved with htaccess. paste these codes in .htaccess file

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: But on localhost also its redirecting to https

Comment: @VivekSadh just do that for your production .htaccess file

Comment: but I can't test anything on localhost. It always redirects to https. I have to manually change it to http then it works.